# Dynamically adding an IValueConverter in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using .NET 3.5

I have a DataGridTextColumn that I want to turn the background color red when the value of that column is false. I have seen this done in XMAL but cannot figure out how to do it in code behind

```
DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Can Connect", Binding = new Binding("CanConnect") };
//How to add the converter here so that the background of the cell turns red when CanConnect = false?

    public class IsConnectedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool input = (bool)value;
            switch (input)
            {
                case true:
                    return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
                default:
                    return Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Converter` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  of the `Binding` class:

```
new Binding("CanConnect") {
    Converter = new IsConnectedConverter()
}
```

In your code, you are assigning your binding to the `Binding` property of the `DataGridTextColumn`, but that property only controls the contents of the cell. For the visual appearance of the cell, you will need a style, which can also be set in code-behind:

```
Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
st.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, binding));
column.CellStyle = st;
```

In that code, `binding` would be a variable with your new `Binding` object (or the above constructor and initialization call right away). As described by the [docs on `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), the target type of the style must be `DataGridCell`, and as that class inherits from `Control`, we can add setters for dependency properties of `Control`, such as `Background`.

I'm afraid I can't test this code right now; I hope it gives you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Hmmm that just puts the string "#FFFF0000" in the column cell. How do I target the background color?

Comment: @Bob: Ah, I was assuming the property you're assigning the `Binding` object to is already the correct one. It seems to me that the background color can only be set with the `Style` property. Please give me a moment to think about some code.

Comment: @Bob: I've updated my answer and hope that this solution works :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm getting the red background color now but also getting the #FFFF0000 in the cell. I should be able to figure it out though. Thanks again

Comment: @Bob: I presume your `Binding` property is still bound to the result of the converter rather than to the data source whose result you actually want to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
var binding = new Binding("CanConnect") {
   Converter = new IsConnectedConverter()
};
DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Can Connect", Binding = binding };
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting Converter you can use `Converter` property of `Binding` class:

```
DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
column.Header = "Can Connect";
Binding binding = new Binding("CanConnect");
binding.Converter = new IsConnectedConverter();
column.Binding = binding;
```

And you should not use `switch` for boolean variable. This is better:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool input = (bool)value;
    if (input)
    {
       return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    return Brushes.Red;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm that just puts the string "#FFFF0000" in the column cell. How do I target the background color?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this. I needed to set the Converter on the binding of the style rather than the binding of the column:

```
        Binding columnBinding = new Binding("CanConnect");
        Binding styleBinding = new Binding("CanConnect") { Converter = new IsConnectedConverter()}; 
        Style st = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
        st.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, styleBinding));
        column.CellStyle = st;
        column.Binding = columnBinding;
        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```